# Orthographic Camera is not Occlusion Culling?

Tags: unity-game-engine, occlusion-culling

In the scene where the occlusion culling is done as desired,

When I change the camera to orthograhpic, occlusion culling is not done.

(Look at the sphere the red arrow points to on the right)

[image]What should I do?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141200/74040

Comment: The cause for this is clearly on Unity's side, either as a bug or as an intentional design decision. It may be that occlusion culling cannot be performed with an orthographic camera due to technical reasons.

Comment: i'm sorry about duplicated posting. i didn't know that.